# Google Map is not loaded for the app downloaded from the Play Store

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I use Google Map in my app. When I install the app from my pc using Eclipse, the Google Map is loaded properly. Now I uploaded the app to the Google Play Store for distribution. For the app installed from the Play Store, Google Map is not loaded. What is wrong or which step am I missing?

EDIT 1:
Now I get the SHA1 fingerprint from the release keystore. Then I go to the Google APIs Console and using exiting project and that fingerprint, I created new Android API Key. That new API key is replaced with my old debug API Key and then I export a new apk again. That apk is uploaded to the play store. It looks I followed all required steps. But still, the map is not loaded and only white color background appeared.
Same thing happened at these links, but no description of how they solve the problem.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293538/cant-run-android-application-with-release-keystore)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#the_google_maps_api_key. check the topic Displaying the release certificate fingerprint use the same in google develoepr console

Comment: Is this on the same device, or two different devices?

Comment: @Raghunandan; So I need to have another API key for the release mode. Using that release mode SHA1 finger print, I will have another API key for the release mode. Is it? Thanks

Comment: @Matt Gibson; only one device

Comment: @batuman yes you need the key

Comment: @Raghunandan; thanks Man. You saved me again. I uploaded to the Play Store with the new version. Once approved, i can test it. Thanks

Comment: @batuman you are welcome and hopefully you get to see the map

Comment: now I use the API Key retrieved using the release keystore's SHA1 finger print. But still I can't see the map at the new version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do following

- Please cross verify package name both in API console and in manifest file.
- Please cross verify API key in both API console and in manifest file.
- Sign the unsigned APK using release keystore

Before uploading to play store,

- Install it whether it displays Map. It should display map, once it works then only upload APK play store.

`Note:` Some time you have to UNINSTALL app which is already installed in device and try to re install new APK, it should work :).

Comment: Very good check list. The package name and the name I put into the SHA1 fingerprint don't match. Now solved, thank you.