# Android Google Maps API v2 not showing content

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating very simple app using Google Maps with Android Studio. To get the API key from Google to use MapsV2 I created a newkey.jks like: **Build -> Generate Signed APK** and I put it in the **folder_name\citieskey.jks**. Then in a **Windows** command line, in my **Jre7** folder I typed: **keytool -list -v -keystore folder_name\citieskey.jks** to create SHA-1, I entered my password and I got my SHA-1 API key after that. I entered everythig I needed in manifest file too and this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

}
```

But when I launch the app I get Google Map with **zoom in** and **zoom out** feature and a blank map.

I read that it could be because the wrong API key or because works only when installed from Google Play store?! Did I miss anything when creating SHA-1?
Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="hr.pavle.cities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBBxVgt8N82IUM_WZYLDs_k4i7Vq5U2_Y4"/>

</application>
```

Comment: Use following link for add marker and content of map(V2) in android.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: add your manifest file

Comment: Check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19750355/1318946

Comment: Thanks, but none of this helps. This is my log: **Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).**